# Why aren't type errors resolved when I install types?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, types, jasmine, eslint

I am using Visual Studio code, typescript, eslint, and Jasmine to write unit tests.

Before I installed eslint, my code compiled and ran fine. Once I installed eslint, I got errors when I ran `npx eslint 'tsc/**'` I also see these errors in Visual Studio.

One of these errors is `'describe' is not defined`. Since this function comes from Jasmine, I realized that I need to install Jasmine types. I did that by typing this on the command line: `npm i -D @types/jasmine`

After installing the types, I still get these errors when I run the command line for eslint and in Visual Studio code. If I open up the `node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts` file, I see this line in it:

```
/**
 * Create a group of specs (often called a suite).
 * @param description Textual description of the group
 * @param specDefinitions Function for Jasmine to invoke that will define inner suites a specs
 */
declare function describe(description: string, specDefinitions: () => void): void;
```

**So why does ESLint still complain that these types are not defined?** I'm very new to all of these technologies, so I'm out of ideas.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["es6","dom"],                           /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "allowJs": false,                         /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "tscbuild",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "rootDir": "tsc",                         /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": true,                    /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "resolveJsonModule": true,                /* Include modules imported with '.json' extension */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
    node: true
  },
  extends: ["airbnb-base"],
  globals: {
    Atomics: "readonly",
    SharedArrayBuffer: "readonly"
  },
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018
  },
  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
  rules: {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
  }
};
```

I realize the error may lie in the way I am using Jasmine, so here's an excerpt of that file:

```
import "jasmine";
import "./app";

console.log("spec");

describe("App", () => {
  describe("rest()", () => {
    it("should subtract actions remaining", () => {
      (global as any).State.variables.actions_remaining = 5;

      (global as any).setup.rest();

      expect((global as any).State.variables.actions_remaining).toBe(4);
    });

    it("will not let you go below zero actions remaining", () => {
      (global as any).State.variables.actions_remaining = 0;

      (global as any).setup.rest();

      expect((global as any).State.variables.actions_remaining).toBe(0);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

okay I got these errors to go away by changing my test:

```
import * as j from "jasmine";
import "./app";

console.log("spec");

j.describe("App", () => {
  j.describe("rest()", () => {
    j.it("should subtract actions remaining", () => {
      (global as any).State.variables.actions_remaining = 5;

      (global as any).setup.rest();

      j.expect((global as any).State.variables.actions_remaining).toBe(4);
    });

    j.it("will not let you go below zero actions remaining", () => {
      (global as any).State.variables.actions_remaining = 0;

      (global as any).setup.rest();

      j.expect((global as any).State.variables.actions_remaining).toBe(0);
    });
```

When you're not using ESLint, you can use Jasmine functions as globals. But to get this to compile, I have to refer to the Jasmine import.

Is there a way to avoid this so I don't have to preface every Jasmine function with `j.` and still get all the benefits of type safety?

Comment: If you use `import { describe } from "jasmine";`?

Comment: @Silvermind This is a better way to solve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764680/can-i-import-a-library-so-that-its-functions-are-available-as-globals-in-one-fi?noredirect=1#comment107509464_60764680

Comment: Ok. No problem. Good luck.