# Can I import a library so that it's functions are available as globals in one file?

Tags: typescript, jasmine, eslint

This is related to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60764625/61624

If you are not using typescript, you can use the Jasmine functions as globals. Once I installed eslint, eslint complained that these global functions were not defined. Is there some way I can import Jasmine into my test so that I can refer to these Jasmine functions as globals, or is the only way to refer to Jasmine the way I have been the answer?

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I would accept that as the answer @jonrsharpe